# What does "to put things into prospective" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Note that it's **prospective**, not **perspective**.

I'm reading a blog post and found below paragraph.

> It is impossible to resist the urge of exploring in-memory OLTP Engine (code 
>   name Hekaton) released as part of SQL Server 2014. This technology can provide 
>   you huge performance boost, assuming, of course, that **you can live within 
>   surface area limitations**. Nevertheless, internal implementation of in-memory 
>   OLTP is fascinating. Almost everything is done differently than what you get 
>   used to with SQL Server Storage Engine. **To put things into prospective**, I 
>   seriously considered to name this post as “Concurrency – 
>   upside down”.

There are two places that I can't fully understood.

- that you can live within surface area limitations
- To put things into prospective

I've looked up those corresponding words in dictionary but still have difficulty in understanding them. Can anyone help me on it? Great thanks.

---

## Edit

There are some technical terms in the paragraph and you may not understand. Just ignore them and focus on the general parts.

Comment: It means the author made an error.

Comment: Closing note: “Concurrency – upside down”. It's a play on the idiom "to put things into perspective," suitably changed to reflect an approach that turns things on their head: *perspective,* look back; *prospective,* look ahead.

Comment: @Kris Who says that *perspective* involves looking back? Used in this sense it is here (it is clearly a typo), it refers to 'a particular attitude toward or way of regarding something; a point of view'.

Comment: @WS2 That's one perspective, of course, that you are entitled to :)

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it seeks to analyse incorrect usages from a non-native or incompetent speaker

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. The piece in question does not appear to be written by a native/competent speaker.

Comment: @WS2: Now I've just looked at the rest of the cited text, I'd say it's screamingly obvious the writer isn't a native speaker. I don't think any "incompetent native speaker" could make that many mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The "*surface area limitations*" refer to considerations that somehow constrain performance in ways that I do not have the knowledge base to completely understand. If you can accomplish your task within these constraints, then the technology being discussed will give performance improvements.

The meaning of "*to put things into prospective*" is that the writer of the Blog:

- does not know the correct idiom, or;
- did not take the time to look it up, and spell "*perspective*" correctly.